# How to enable WebLogic digest authentication with WLST

Tags: docker, weblogic, digest, wlst

Is it possible to enable the WebLogic digest authentication with WLST script or by other automated means?

I'm using [official Oracle WebLogic docker images](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleWebLogic), and configure them with WLST scripts during the image build. However, I don't find a way to enable digest passwords using the WLST. Also, enabling it by hand on the admin console requires the restart, which essentially destroys the container, as the WebLogic process is the entrypoint.

How could I automatically enable the digest during the image build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show you the Online mode commands, you can easily convert them to scripts.

Just make sure you replace username/password and your domain name in the commands.

```
connect('weblogicUser','weblogicPassword','t3://localhost:7001')
edit()
cd ('SecurityConfiguration/replace_your_domain_name_here/Realms/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultAuthenticator')
startEdit()
set('PasswordDigestEnabled','true')
save()
stopEdit()
exit()
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The following exception is thrown: `The requested attribute is not exposed through JMX: setPasswordDigestEnabled: Attribute is readonly. : Security:Name=myrealmDefaultAuthenticator:PasswordDigestEnabled`

Comment: @TuomasToivonen Did you edit() and startEdit() ? this means lock and edit didnt work.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen make sure you mark as answer so we can help others.